# If $M$ is an $n$-dimensional compact complex manifold with $b_n(M) = 0$, then $H^{n,0}(M)=H^{0,n}(M)=0$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I am recently reading a paper and it mentioned that an $n$-dimensional compact complex manifold $M$  with Betti number $b_n(M) = 0$ has vanishing Dolbeault cohomology groups $H^{n,0}(M)$, $H^{0,n}(M)$.

Then it states a Lemma holds for this kind of manifold, but it only requires an $n$-dimensional compact complex manifold $M$ with no holomorphic $n$-form.

Since $H^{n,0}(M) \cong H^0(M, \Omega_{Hol}^n)$, $\Omega_{Hol}^n$ is the sheaf of holomorphic $n$-forms, it is obvious that $H^{n,0}(M) = \{0\}$ and by Serre Duality, $H^{0,n}(M) = H^{n,0}(M) = \{0\}$.

The proof of the first statement is said to be in this paper:
Gray, A., A property of a hypothetical complex structure on the six sphere, Bol. Un. Mat.
Ital. B (7) 11 (1997), Suppl. fasc. 2, 251^255.
But I cannot find it anywhere on the internet. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no holomorphic $n$-forms on $M$, then $H^{n,0}_{\bar{\partial}}(M) = 0$ follows immediately from Dolbeault's Theorem. If instead you only know that $b_n(M) = 0$, then you need the following result.

**Proposition:** If $M$ is a compact complex $n$-dimensional manifold, then there is an injective map $H^{n,0}_{\bar{\partial}}(M) \to H^n_{\text{dR}}(M, \mathbb{C})$.

**Proof:** Note that

$$H^{n,0}_{\bar{\partial}}(M) = \frac{\ker\left(\bar{\partial} : \mathcal{E}^{n,0}(M) \to \mathcal{E}^{n,1}(M)\right)}{\operatorname{im}\left(\bar{\partial} : \mathcal{E}^{n,-1}(M) \to \mathcal{E}^{n,0}(M)\right)} = \ker\left(\bar{\partial} : \mathcal{E}^{n,0}(M) \to \mathcal{E}^{n,1}(M)\right).$$

So if $\alpha \in H^{n,0}_{\bar{\partial}}(M)$, then $\bar{\partial}\alpha = 0$. On the other hand, $\partial\alpha \in \mathcal{E}^{n+1,0}(M) = \{0\}$, so $\partial\alpha = 0$. Therefore $d\alpha = \partial\alpha + \bar{\partial}\alpha = 0$. So there is an element $[\alpha] \in H^n_{\text{dR}}(M, \mathbb{C})$.

To see that the map $H^{n,0}_{\bar{\partial}}(M) \to H^n_{\text{dR}}(M, \mathbb{C})$, $\alpha\mapsto[\alpha]$ is injective, suppose $[\alpha] = 0$, i.e. $\alpha = d\beta$ for some $(n-1)$-form $\beta$. Then

$$\int_M\alpha\wedge\bar{\alpha} = \int_M d\beta\wedge\overline{d\beta} = \int_M d\beta\wedge d\bar{\beta} = \int_M d(\beta\wedge d\bar{\beta}) = 0$$

by Stokes' Theorem. On the other hand, in local holomorphic coordinates $(U, z^j)$ with $z^j = x^j + iy^j$, we have $\alpha|_U = fdz^1\wedge\dots\wedge dz^n$, so

\begin{align*}
(\alpha\wedge\bar{\alpha})|_U &= \alpha|_U\wedge\bar{\alpha}|_U\\
&= |f|^2 dz^1\wedge\dots\wedge dz^n\wedge d\bar{z}^1\wedge\dots\wedge d\bar{z}^n\\ 
&= (-1)^{n(n-1)/2}|f|^2dz^1\wedge d\bar{z}^1\wedge\dots dz^n\wedge d\bar{z}^n\\
&= (-2i)^n(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}|f|^2 dx^1\wedge dy^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n\wedge dy^n.
\end{align*}

If $n$ is even, then $(-2i)^n(-1)^{n(n-1)/2} = 2^n$, so we see that $\displaystyle\int_U\alpha\wedge\bar{\alpha} \geq 0$ with equality if and only if $f = 0$ (and hence $\alpha|_U = 0$). As $\displaystyle\int_M\alpha\wedge\bar{\alpha}$ is a sum of such integrals and $\displaystyle\int_M\alpha\wedge\bar{\alpha} = 0$, we see that $\alpha|_U$ for every coordinate chart and hence $\alpha = 0$.

For $n$ odd, the argument is similar, except now $(-2i)^n(-1)^{n(n-1)/2} = 
-2^ni$ so the integrals involved are purely imaginary with non-positive imaginary part. $\square$

This style of proof can be found in (at least) the following two places:

- section $2.1$ of Angella's [*Hodge numbers of a hypothetical complex structure on $S^6$*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.10518), and
- lemma $2.2$ of Brown's [*Properties of a hypothetical exotic complex structure on $\mathbb{CP}^3$*](https://www.emis.de/journals/MB/132.1/mb132_1_7.pdf).

Note however that instead of arguing locally to prove $\alpha = 0$, the first paper uses an observation about the Hodge dual of $\alpha$.

With the above proposition at hand, if $b_n(M) = 0$, then we have

$$\dim_{\mathbb{C}} H^{n,0}_{\bar{\partial}}(M) \leq \dim_{\mathbb{C}} H^n_{\text{dR}}(M, \mathbb{C}) = b_n(M) = 0$$

so $H^{n,0}_{\bar{\partial}}(M) = 0$. Finally, Serre duality gives $H^{0, n}_{\bar{\partial}}(M) \cong H^{n,0}_{\bar{\partial}}(M) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you, I've already edited the question.